# Adding custom CSS / JavaScript to Certain CMS Pages With Custom JS Path

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cms, static-block

I tried the both ways,

**Method 1**:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem">
       <type>skin_js</type><name>js/myJs.js</name>
   </action>
</reference>
```

> The above gives default skin directory.

**Method 2**:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addJs"><script>myJs.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

> The above gives js directory.

But I Need the file located like the below to add via block and reference head.

**src Path:** http://www.example.com/wp/folder1/folder2/script.js

Here the `http://www.example.com` is store url.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try bellow  way

> Add custom CSS or JavaScript to CMS Pages With Custom JS Path

```
<reference name="head">
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/your_foldername/your_js_name.js</name></action> 
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/your_foldername/your_css_name.css</name><params/></action>
</reference>
```

Go admin side and add above code in CMS page in section `(Layout Update XML)`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Login as Admin at your Magento store and once you are logged in to the Dashboard, navigate to the following...

**System** > **Configuration** > **General** > **Design** > **Miscellaneous Scripts**

Enter the following markup in the Miscellaneous Scripts text field box

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp/folder1/folder2/custom.js"></script>
```

Click **Save Config** to save your entry and that is all.

You may need to refresh your **cache** therefore if prompted navigate to **System** > **Cache Management** and refresh the appropriate caches.

Comment: this is not added Certain CMS Pages With Custom JS Path

Comment: Correct however the OP asked for the file to be located in the following way http://www.example.com/wp/folder1/folder2/script.js

Using skin_Js or skin_css refers to Magento's theme folder.

Answer (score -1):

**To add a CSS file residing in the skin CSS folder**

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addCss">
      <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
   </action>
</reference>
```

**To add a Javascript file residing in the skin JS folder**

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem">
      <type>skin_js</type>
      <name>js/custom.js</name>
      <params/>
   </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately your answer does not really help with the issue in the question, how to add a JS source **outside** the skin directory.

Comment: so do i need to delete this answer ?